# How to Validate input inside of a radio button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate for this and have 3 radio buttons, two of which have an input where they can put a price. I need it so one of the 3 radio buttons must be selected, and if it's one of the first 2 I need them to also have a price in there. Will I need to create an additional method somehow? I've included some of other other validation i'm using on the page, but the html just shows the piece i'm working on.

```js
    // Validation
$(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
          return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/mycorporatedomain.com/.test(value);
        }, "Please specify the correct domain for your documents");


        jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkmeout", function(value, element) { 
            return this.optional(element) || /^\s*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(value);
        },"Required");

        $('#addProductForm').validate({
            rules: {
                productName: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 40,
                    required: true,
                    checkmeout: true
                },
                categoryPlaceholder: {
                    required: true,
                    errorClass: "testing"
                },
                productDescriptionShort: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 250,
                    required: false,
                    checkmeout: true
                },
                productDetailsLong: {
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 500,
                    required: true,
                    checkmeout: true
                },
                 productFCState: {
                    required: true
                },
                 productCategory: {
                    required: true
                }
            },

            messages: {
                    productName: {
                        minlength: "Your product name must be between 2 and 40 characters",
                        required: ""
                    }, 
                    categoryPlaceholder: {
                        required: ""
                    },
                    productDescriptionShort: {
                        minlength: "Your product description must be between 2 and 250 characters",
                        required: ""
                    },
                    productDetailsLong: {
                        minlength: "Your product description must be between 2 and 500 characters",
                        required: ""
                    },
            },

            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },

            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },

            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block-error',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else if(element.parent('#productCategory').length) {
                    error.insertAfter('.list-group.list-group-root');
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

```css
#itemFeatured {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.radio label::after {
    background-color: #3390ce;
}

.height-initial {
    height: initial;
}

#itemPricing .form-inline {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#itemPricing .form-inline label {
    width: 120px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/0.3.7/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>




 <form id="addProductForm">
<div id="itemPricing" class="clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" form-group="">
      <label for="itemPricing" class="required" aria-required="true">Pricing</label>
      <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Select how you want pricing to display on your website.</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Regular Price -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <div class="form-inline radio-input-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" class="height-initial" name="pricingOptions" id="regularPrice" value="">
          <label for="regularPrice" class="required" aria-required="true">Regular Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="productPrice" name="productPrice">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline radio-input-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" class="height-initial" name="pricingOptions" id="salePrice" value="">
          <label for="salePrice" class="required" aria-required="true">Sale Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control money" id="productPrice" name="productPrice">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline radio-input-group">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" class="height-initial" name="pricingOptions" id="emailPrice" value="">
          <label for="emailPrice" class="required" aria-required="true">Email for Price</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
   <div class="pull-right">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in">Save</button>
                            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please explain it.

Comment: How can I validate this form so that this group is required in that the user must select one of the radio options, and if it is one of the first two, they must also have a number in the input.

Comment: You've accidentally duplicated the `productPrice` field twice on the page.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I validate this form so that this group is required in that the user must select one of the radio options, ... ?

Simply make it `required`.

```
$('#addProductForm').validate({
    rules: {
        pricingOptions: {
            required: true
        }, ....
```

You'll then have to conditionally tweak the `errorPlacement`.

---

> ... and if it is one of the first two, they must also have a number in the input?

Conditionally apply the `required` rule to the text fields based on the radio selection...

```
$('#addProductForm').validate({
    rules: {
        pricingOptions: {
            required: true
        },
        productPrice: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('#regularPrice').is(':checked');
            }
        },
        productPriceSale: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $('#salePrice').is(':checked');
            }
        }, ....
```

You've accidentally duplicated the `productPrice` field twice on the page.  You cannot have duplicate `id`.

---

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/spr29o36/](http://jsfiddle.net/spr29o36/)

Comment: Any idea why the highlight isn't adding the has-error class to the closest form-group? I'd like to use that to apply some css to visually show that it has an error

Comment: @JacobJ, it does add the class.  Disable `unhighlight` to see it for yourself.  The problem is the `unhighight` function is simultaneously being triggered by the valid fields on the form.  Your `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions are too generic.... multiple fields are targeting the same `closest('form-group')`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should link your local js file, otherwise the browser could not execute it:

```
<script src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

Next you must give an id to every form you will need in your js, in this case, you have to give an id to the button, for example, change your html line to this one:

```
<button id="saveButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success save ladda-button" data-style="zoom-in">Save</button>
```

Now you'll have access to that button, and you will be able to validate whatever you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#saveButton").click(function(){
        switch($('input[name=pricingOptions]:checked').val()){
            case "1": 
                if($("#productPrice").val() == "")
                    console.log("bad");
                else console.log("good");
                break;
            case "2": 
                if($("#salePrice").val() == "")
                    console.log("bad");
                else console.log("good"); break;
            case "3": console.log("good"); break;
            default: console.log("bad");
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that I take the value of pricingOptions, in the HTML file you must give a different value to each radio option.

Comment: Please note that the OP is asking about how to use the jQuery Validate plugin.